# How to get \coloneqq the other way round?

Tags: symbols

The question is basically in the title. How do I get `=:` instead of the usual `:=` which is produced by `\coloneqq`? Is there command or do I have to created a new one? If the latter, is there an "usual" way to do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Did you see the see the mathtools manual section 3.7.3?

Comment: I haven't, thank you very much. (For any else beeing as clueless as me: The answer is (somewhat obviously) \eqqcolon )